# Twig Loader prependPath not working

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to use theme in symfony 2.5.6 following this tutorial : http://www.ahmed-samy.com/symofny2-twig-multiple-domains-templating/

So I tried this in the TemplateListener (declared as service)

```
$path = dirname(__DIR__) . '/Resources/themes/' . $theme . '/views';
$this->twig->getLoader()->prependPath($path, 'MyWebsiteFront');
```

But this does not work, the template "MyWebsiteFront:Index:index.html.twig" is not found (but it exists at C:\www\MyWebsiteFront\src\MyWebsiteFront\Resources\themes\mytheme\views\Index\index.html.twig, the path generated by $path)

Any ideas ?

Comment: How are you referencing this template? Are you loading it from a controller with `$this->render('MyWebsiteFront::Index:index.html.twig', array(...))` or are you using it in twig, with `{% extends 'MyWebsiteFront::Index:index.html.twig' %}`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html), When you render the template you need to reference it with the namespace you aliased to that path e.g.

```
@MyWebsiteFront/Index/index.html.twig
```

> When using the setPaths(), addPath(), and prependPath() methods,
>   specify the namespace as the second argument (when not specified,
>   these methods act on the "main" namespace):
>
> ```
> $loader->addPath($templateDir, 'admin'); Namespaced templates can be
> ```
>
> accessed via the special @namespace_name/template_path notation:
>
> ```
> $twig->render('@admin/index.html', array());
> ```

*NOTE: The namespace is not required.*